# plotting a DataFrame in 3D surfaceplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have a dataframe (size: 1008,100). the values of cells are within 0.1 and 1. I would like to visualize it in a surface plot but i cannot really figure out what the x,y and z values are gonna be. I'd like to position the surface plot like the rows(1008) is the aligned with the x axis and the columns(100) is aligned with the y axis.
Any help is much appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Take a look again at [ask] and creating a [mcve]. You should also add the tag for the language this is about (Python?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `x` and `y` you are looking for can be created with [meshgrid](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html). A good way to start is to find an example on the [matplotlib gallery](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/index.html) and make [changes from there](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d_3.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-surface3d-3-py). As an example:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create a data frame with 1008x100 values between 0.1 and 1.0
xs = np.arange(0, 1008)
ys = np.arange(0,100)
zs = np.square(xs[:, np.newaxis]) * np.square(ys[np.newaxis, :])
max_value = np.max(zs)
min_value = np.min(zs)
zs = (zs - min_value) / (max_value - min_value) * 0.9 + 0.1

data = pd.DataFrame(zs)

# create X and Y with np.meshgrid and the 2D data frame
#  (reusing the scratch variable xs and ys)
xs = np.arange(data.shape[0])   # [0,1,....,1007]
ys = np.arange(data.shape[1])   # [0,1,...,99]

X, Y = np.meshgrid(xs, ys)

# create a surface plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, data.T)
```

( note: i needed to transpose the `data` with `.T`, don't know why, sometime it is needed...)